# O que tem de errado nesta query?

Tags: mysql

Eu estou querendo fazer uma subtração do valor total de uma coluna de uma tabela, com o valor total de uma coluna de outra tabela.

Query:

```
SELECT (
    SUM(r.valor_receita) - 
    (
        SELECT SUM(d.valor_despesa)
        FROM 
            despesas AS d 
        WHERE 
            YEAR(d.data_vencimento) = YEAR(r.data_vencimento)
            AND MONTH(d.data_vencimento) <= MONTH(r.data_vencimento) 
            AND d.id_usuario = r.id_usuario)
    ) AS saldo_previsto
FROM 
    receitas AS r 
WHERE 
    YEAR(r.data_vencimento) = '2017' 
    AND MONTH(r.data_vencimento) <= '06' 
    AND r.id_usuario = 1
```

Na cláusula `where` da tabela 'despesas' deve ser o mesmo valor da cláusula `where` de receitas.

**EDIT:**
Tabelas: https://pastebin.com/rexcXTKw

Assim deveria ser a query:

```
SELECT (
    SUM(r.valor_receita) - 
    (
        SELECT SUM(d.valor_despesa)
        FROM 
            despesas AS d 
        WHERE 
            YEAR(d.data_vencimento) = '2017'
            AND MONTH(d.data_vencimento) <= '06'
            AND d.id_usuario = 1)
    ) AS saldo_previsto
FROM 
    receitas AS r 
WHERE 
    YEAR(r.data_vencimento) = '2017' 
    AND MONTH(r.data_vencimento) <= '06' 
    AND r.id_usuario = 1
```

A única diferença é que estou passando novamente os parâmetros de ano, mês, e id de usuário. Tem alguma maneira de fazer isso funcionar sem ter que passar os valores duas vezes?

Comment: Que erro está dando?

Comment: Não está retornando erro... Na verdade o que acontece é que ele não retorna o valor que deveria retornar...
Ele deveria somar todas as receitas (tabela receitas) e subtrair por todas as despesas (tabela despesas), quando o ano for igual ao ano selecionado e o mês menor ou igual ao mês selecionado.. sendo esta condição para as duas tabelas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente fazer algo assim:

```
select sum(receitas_dia) - sum(despesas_dia)
from (
    select
        SUM(r.valor_receita) as receitas_dia,
        (
            select SUM(d.valor_despesa) 
            from despesas as d 
            where d.data_vencimento = r.data_vencimento
              and d.id_usuario = r.id_usuario) as despesas_dia
    from 
        receitas as r 
    where 
        year(r.data_vencimento) = '2017' 
        and month(r.data_vencimento) <= '06'
    group by r.data_vencimento) as receita_despesas;
```

Neste caso, duas consultas são feitas. A primeira serve para alinhar somar as despesas e receitas por data. Após isso, é feito a soma das colunas e então a subtração.

Obs.: Não testei a consulta no MySQL, apenas no SQLServer. Talvez precise adaptar algo para o MySQL.

Comment: Em meu primeiro teste funcionou perfeito! Preciso testar alguns casos para ver se realmente está ok... por agora está funcionando bem! Valeu!
Qualquer coisa eu retorno aqui para falar...